# R: Is there a way to print a data frame with some separators inserted between rows?

Tags: r, printing

I bascially want to format my dataframe print. I would like to choose for each column if the text is centered or not and after some defined rows insert a 1px separator. Furthermore it would be great to define for each column the width. With what function is that possible? I would like to output that later on to a textfile, and don't want to use Latex.

EDIT:

I just want to print a dataframe to a textfile, but as a nicely formatted table. So that it looks like an Excel sheet where you hide the gridlines. After x rows I want to basically just have a separator line ("----------") filling the whole width of the table.

Example:

```
My Data Frame consists of the following data:
Row1: "Test Entry 1", 5, 75, 0.3
Row2: "Test 2", 0.3, 1, 0.5

Output should be
Test Entry 1    5    75    0.3
------------------------------
Test 2        0.3    1     0.5
```

I hope it's more clear now :)

Comment: Are you trying to format a data frame to a plain text file? Or some kind of markup? How are you going to specify 1px? This doesn't make much sense and you've not given us any examples to work with. Please try harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably better off using one of the table packages but if you *really really* want to do it you can try something like this (pretty rudimentary, but can be expanded)

```
df<-data.frame(Test=sample(c("Test 1","Test 2","Test 3"),10,replace=T),
               D1=round(runif(10)*10,2),
               D2=round(runif(10)*10,2),
               D3=round(runif(10)*10,2))


sepwidth<-60
colwidth<-10
require(plyr)
ddply(df,.(Test),function(d){
  print(noquote(apply(d,c(1:2),function(p)paste0(paste0(rep(" ",colwidth-length(p)),collapse=""),p,collapse=""))));
  print(noquote(paste0(rep("-",sepwidth),collapse="")))
  return(NULL)})

Test            D1            D2            D3           
[1,]          Test 1          5.37          3.48          1.19
[2,]          Test 1          9.49          9.51          9.44
[3,]          Test 1          8.52          6.53          4.10
[4,]          Test 1          0.72          0.20          0.20
[5,]          Test 1          2.70          6.19          8.17
[1] ------------------------------------------------------------
  Test            D1            D2            D3           
[1,]          Test 2          0.61          0.96          2.17
[2,]          Test 2          6.85          2.36          6.90
[3,]          Test 2          8.99          2.86          2.32
[1] ------------------------------------------------------------
  Test            D1            D2            D3           
[1,]          Test 3          0.23          6.42          9.41
[2,]          Test 3          1.53          1.84          4.60
[1] ------------------------------------------------------------
```